# Disallow child elements to inherit styles from parent element/s

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

A `<p:fileUpload>`, for example is ususally displayed something like the following.

[image]

It basically renders an HTML table among some other HTML elements. The generated table code looks like the following.

```
<table class="ui-fileupload-files">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="ui-fileupload-preview">
                <canvas width="80" height="60"></canvas>
            </td>

            <td>Winter.jpg</td>
            <td>103.1 KB</td>

            <td class="ui-fileupload-progress">
                <div class="ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                    <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style="display: none; width: 0%;"></div>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <button class="ui-fileupload-cancel ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only">
                    <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
                    <span class="ui-button-text">ui-button</span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please notice that there is no border around table cells (among other styles) (rules in HTML tables).

---

If this `<p:fileUpload>` is displayed inside a `<p:dataTable>`, for example, styles from `<p:dataTable>` are automatically applied to the table which is displayed for a `<p:fileUpload>` as shown below.

[image]

Styles from the given `<p:dataTable>` are applied to the `<p:fileUpload>` as can be seen in the picture.

This `<p:fileUpload>` can be displayed by the following XHTML code.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="row" value="Value"
             rows="3"
             rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
             style="width: 50%;">

    <p:column headerText="Index">
        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Image">
        <p:graphicImage id="image"
                        library="default"
                        name="test/Sunset.jpg"
                        height="100" width="100"/>

        <p:overlayPanel for="image"
                        at="left top" my="right bottom" 
                        style="width: 500px; display: none;"
                        showCloseIcon="true" dismissable="true">

            <p:fileUpload fileLimit="1"
                          allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                          fileUploadListener="#{bean.listener}"/>
        </p:overlayPanel>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Can this be prevented anyway so that styles from `<p:dataTable>` are not applied to `<p:fileUpload>` and the `<p:fileUpload>` can be displayed as usual as shown in the first picture?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, You have to override all those values manually if you don't want it them use parent's css.

Comment: Right. I will go without it.